# Magento 2.3 ZoomMeeting with web SDK

Tags: magento2.3, react

I am integrating zoom meeting into magento 2.3.

I have added following code in requirejs-config.js to import/include the 3rd party js files :

```
var config = {
map: {
    '*': {
        react: 'https://source.zoom.us/1.8.6/lib/vendor/react.min.js',
        reactDom: 'https://source.zoom.us/1.8.6/lib/vendor/react-dom.min.js',
        redux: 'https://source.zoom.us/1.8.6/lib/vendor/redux.min.js',
        reduxThunk: 'https://source.zoom.us/1.8.6/lib/vendor/redux-thunk.min.js',
        loadSh: 'https://source.zoom.us/1.8.6/lib/vendor/lodash.min.js',
        meeting: 'https://source.zoom.us/zoom-meeting-1.8.6.min.js'
    }
},
shim: {
    'react': {
        'deps': ["jquery"]
    },
    'reactDom': {
        'deps': ["react","jquery"]
    },
    'meeting': {
        'deps': ["react", "reactDom","redux","reduxThunk","loadSh","jquery"]
    }
},
deps :['domReady!']
```

};

But it gives me an error in browser console. Can anyone help me out from this error?

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: React is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (zoom-meeting-1.8.6.min.js:2)
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it to work, but it's quite a clunky method.  It boils down to Zoom relying on global declarations of everything, and requirejs like to scope the scripts to the module.  Forget about using shims with this.

```
define(["dataservice", "text!./zoom-tool.html", "react", "reactDom", "redux", "reduxThunk", "lodash", "cryptojs"], 
    function (dataservice, htmlString, react, reactdom, redux, reduxthunk) {
    
    window.React = react;
    window.ReactDOM = reactdom;
    window.Redux = redux;
    window.ReduxThunk = reduxthunk;
    require(['zoom']);

...    do zoom things here...
```

Comment: Hi, I had solved the issue by removing default magento js & css via xml. 
There was some js conflict with zoom library & mage/requirejs/mixins.js